# manejo de preferencias en IOs con SWIFT

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Buenos días, estoy comenzando con **swift**, y tengo la duda de como gestionar las preferencias.

En **android**, cuando las trato, si el usuario no la ha modificado tengo una por defecto:

```
String correo = prefs.getString("email", "por_defecto@email.com");
```

De esta manera, si no hay nada almacenada me devuelve el segundo valor...bien, pues es lo que me gustaría, que si no tiene ningún valor almacenado por el usuario, tenga uno por defecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let mail = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mail") ?? "mail@defecto"
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera facil es con UserDefaults.La sintaxis es para Swift 3,varia para otras versiones de Swift.

```
 var email = ""
if let mail = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mail") {
  // Si existe una clave mail es que se ha creado anteriormente
  // en la variable mail se guarda el valor del contenido
  email = mail
} else { 
  // No existe la clave
  email = "email@pordefecto"  
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! esto me sirve!, pero,no hay una manera directa de hacerlo? gracias :)

Comment: No se a que te referieres con algo mas directo.Lo mas facil para guardar preferencias es UserDefaults.

Comment: si perdona Jose, me explico. Con mas directo me refiero al estilo de Android, que con una sentencia recupera una cadena o la que tiene por defecto almacenada

Comment: Bueno,el metodo para extraer una cadena es opcional ,lo mas minimalista que se me ocurre es: